# Symfony3 404 exception response return with status code 200 instead of 500

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.1, symfony3.x

I am new in symfony,I have facing one problem in Production Environment after I add **kernel.event_subscriber** in service.yml. problem is before adding event subscriber in service.yml file It return 500 HTTP_STATUS_CODE & Resource Not Found exception occur with my custom page in twingbuddle That I set, below page it show before add event_subscriber In Service.yml When I go to URL: **http://localhost/meopin_2/trunk/web/en/login/ddssssssssss**,

[image]

Then I add below code in Service.yml

**kernel.event_subscriber:

         class:   AppBundle\EventSubscriber\TokenSubscriber

         arguments:  ["@security.http_utils","@service_container","@router", {}, {}, {},{}]

         tags:

            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, channel: 'kernel' ,event: onKernelController,method: onKernelController}**

and make a File Event Describer. Now issue is When I go to Same URL: **http://localhost/meopin_2/trunk/web/en/login/ddssssssssss**

It Return me Error as a Text Message with HTTP_STATUS_CODE 200, Below response It Return Me Instead of My Previous 404 Page in Production Environment.

[image]

What I missing or Wrong So that It return error as a text message in Production Environment ?

Thanks In Advance if Any one help me.

Comment: Do you have this issue in Dev environment?

Comment: Yes same issue In dev Environment But I test using Production Environment

Comment: you already clear cache in prod  ?  like this: php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

Comment: yes I have clear cache in prod but issue is same